# displaying map location based on address in DB

Tags: android, database, google-maps

I have a working app and db with addresses (in item search app) I need to display on a google map. When user click search he get item details and vendor's details from db,including address and all that is shown on second activity. all that works but only one location is shown on map for all products. **Question is how to to display (on third activity that i already have, with working map display) on map specific DB address depending on its location?**

**DetaljiProizvoda.java** (Item's details)

```
public class DetaljiProizvoda extends Activity {

protected TextView naziv;
protected TextView kategorija;
protected TextView tvrtka;
protected TextView telefonTvrtke;
protected TextView adresaTvrtke;
protected int proizvodId;
protected Cursor cursor; //dodatak na finalni activity prikaza lokacije proizvoda
protected ListAdapter adapter; //dodatak na finalni activity prikaza lokacije proizvoda


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detalji_proizvoda);
    //hvatanje parametra (ID iz tablice) Intenta iz ListaProizvoda activity-a
    proizvodId = getIntent().getIntExtra("PROIZVODI_ID", 0);
    SQLiteDatabase db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT proizv._id, proizv.naziv, proizv.tvrtka, proizv.cijena, proizv.kategorija, proizv.telefonTvrtke, proizv.adresaTvrtke FROM proizvodi proizv LEFT OUTER JOIN proizvodi mgr ON proizv._id = mgr._id WHERE proizv._id = ?", 
            new String[]{""+proizvodId});

    if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        naziv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.naziv);
        naziv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("naziv"))); /*+ " " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastName")));*/

        kategorija = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kategorija);
        kategorija.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("kategorija")));

        tvrtka = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvrtka);
        tvrtka.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tvrtka")));

        telefonTvrtke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.telefonTvrtke);
        telefonTvrtke.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("telefonTvrtke")));

        adresaTvrtke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adresaTvrtke);
        adresaTvrtke.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("adresaTvrtke")));

    }
    //zatvaranje baze
    cursor.close();
    db.close(); 

}

  //default button handler
    public void changeActivity(View view) { 
        startActivity(new Intent(this, GMapsActivity.class));
    }                    

}
```

**GMapsActivity.java**

```
public class GMapsActivity extends MapActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    private static final int latitudeE6 = 37985339;
    private static final int longitudeE6 = 23716735;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gmaps_layout);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);       
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitudeE6, longitudeE6);
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello", "I'm in Athens, Greece!");

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

        MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

        mapController.animateTo(point);
        mapController.setZoom(6);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**gmaps_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true" 
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:apiKey="0vwcQJvEOXRQcyAhZxPToaeuss2Lhodp_qGYkTA" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**DetaljiProizvoda.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/naziv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kategorija"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvrtka"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/telefonTvrtke"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adresaTvrtke"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:onClick="changeActivity"
        android:text="@string/prikazi_lokaciju"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

also **CustomItemizedOverlay.java** file

Comment: If I a right, You want to pass parameters to your GMap Activity?

Comment: yes, more precisely, every address from database and based on that address i should display its related map. i created button "show map location" on detalji_proizvoda.xml that is perfectly working, but only for single location on map